# DTM & GTM together - code error - Uncaught TypeError: w[l].push is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, adobe-analytics

I have an issue with standard GTM script and the error I'm getting is:

> Uncaught TypeError: w[l].push is not a function

The website has both DTM code and GTM code on.

I suspect there is some script interference that is causing that, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot from Chrome Console]

The website in question is seat.co.nz

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help

Comment: Quick 2 second look at the (incredibly slow and unresponsive) site shows that DTM and GTM are both using `dataLayer` namespace.  Something related to DTM sets `dataLayer` as an object with lots of methods etc.  vs. GTM which expects `dataLayer` to be an array.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it could have been part of the solution, so I've updated GTM code to use a different name for its data layer. Wasn't expecting that to be the only reason for the error. Thanks for your 2 second look, appreciate your time.